# Assign symbolic link to an array of files

Tags: python, loops, symlink

(preface: I'm brand new to coding!)
I have a folder full of files, which I need to assign symbolic links to a set within those files.

Currently I am able to to create my list of files I want to use:

```
FilesICareAbout = []
filestart = 82
fileend = 96
nums = np.arange(filestart,fileend+1,1)
for i in range(len(filenames)):
    if i in nums:
        FilesICareAbout.append(filenames[i])
print(FilesICareAbout)
```

I now want to be able to assign a symbolic link to those files and I don't know how...
I know that I can use the os.symlink(src,dst) but unsure how to put in the files that I've got in my FilesICareAbout array as that is now a list and not a string

Comment: Have you actually tried using `os.symlink`? It sounds like it'd work, and the particular issue you're having with it is pretty unclear. Give it a try and specify what exactly you don't understand about it! :)

Comment: If I then try to do 
'''
for x in range(len(FilesICareAbout)):
    os.symlink(FilesICareAbout,'filepath/')
'''
it doesn't work because the src needs to be a string not a list and I don't understand how to make it put in the file name that I have in the list

Comment: Take a look at [the docs for `os.symlink`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.symlink): you need to give it actual paths for the new symlinks it's supposed to create. Your source files seem to be `FilesICareAbout[i]`, you'll have to iterate over `i`. If `dst` is set to the same thing for every symlink, you'll end up with multiple links leading to the same location, "filepath/"... probably not what you intend to do?

I know at least your explanation here doesn't make it obvious for me what you're trying to do here, and if you can explain it here, it'll be much easier to program it!

Comment: `for file in FilesICareAbout:
    os.symlink(file,'/Users/icantcode/Documents/PhD/Testing/')`

this gives an error saying file exists (I assumed src was the file you want to create a link for??). I just want links to these files in a separate folder so I can run them through some other piece of code without having to copy and paste files over as it's multiple GB of data lol

Comment: You've got `src` right, `dst` is *not* the directory into which the new symlink should be placed; it's the actual file path, directory and name included, for your new symlink. You're just a step away from figuring this out :) The error comes from the Testing directory existing, btw. Good luck with your PhD! :D